Can I axiomatize vector space using first order logic?
Hi I'm learning first order logic and found that it is hard to describe vector space in first order logic.
The structure in first order logic is like $\left<M,I\right>$ where $M$ is the element field and $I$ build up the relations between elements and symbols (constant, functional and predicate)
Due to this fact, it seems hard to separate the field of a vector space and vectors it self. So that I cannot describe theorems like $\forall \{a,b\}\subset F,\forall \vec{v}\subset V$ we have $(ab)\vec{v}=a(b\vec{v})$
Thus I would like to ask if first order logic can be used to describe vector space theorem?

There are a couple ways to do this.
One approach is to fold the field of scalars into the language: so, there is no single "language of vector spaces" as such, but rather for each field $k$ we get a language $L_k$ of "$k$-vector spaces." Specifically, this language has a binary function symbol $+$ for vector addition and for each scalar $\alpha\in k$ a unary function symbol $m_\alpha$ for multiplication by $\alpha$. Note that this language generally (= as long as the field is infinite) does not allow us to express predicates like "$\{x,y\}$ is linearly independent;" whether this is a pathological weakness or a useful structural feature depends on the context.
Alternatively, we can use sorts - or, if you don't like sorts, you can use unary predicates $S$(calar) and $V$(ector). To deal with the fact that functions aren't allowed to have restricted domain in first-order logic, we can replace e.g. vector addition with the ternary relation corresponding to the graph of vector addition $\{(x,y,z): x+y=z\}$.

Thanks a lot, I would like to confirm:

is the first approach is to add constant symbol into the language, and adding related axiom according these constant symbol??(which means may result in uncountable axioms)



For the second approach, which means using  predicate symbol to replace function symbol, which means if I need to reference the result I need to make another formula as my axiom, for example to express $ (ab)\vec{v}=a(b\vec{v})$ I need to do like this $(\forall x_1(...(\forall x_7(P_\times(x_1,x_2,x_3)\land P_\cdot(x_3,x_4,x_5)\land P_\cdot(x_2,x_4,x_6)\land P_\cdot(x_1,x_6,x_7))\to(x_5\hat{=}x_7))...))$


where $P_\times$ is the field multiplication, and $P_\cdot$ is field multiply by vector, $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are field elements, $x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7$ are vectors

@Shore Re: approach 1, that's not quite correct; as I wrote, we add unary function symbols to the language. Each $m_\alpha$ denotes the function $x\mapsto \alpha x$.

Re: approach 2, though, that's correct: "relationalization" does result in much longer formulas (which is a good reason for modifying the semantics of FOL to allow partial functions in my opinion, incidentally).

Which means that any $a$ in field $K$ has a special unary function symbol $f_a$ which for any vector $\vec{v}$ in $V$ we have $f_a(\vec{v})=a\vec{v}$. And the structure of the language is all the vectors?? I think this may also result in uncountable axioms??

@Shore Yes, the only objects of the structure are the vectors themselves and the language is as big as the field of scalars involved.

BTW, I think the approach 2 relies on the detailed description of predicate. I'm worry that if I can fully describe vector space using that, since predicate such as $P_\times$ may be anything, and for all $(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in P_\times$ I need to make sure that exist $d_i,e_i$ so that $(a_i,b_i,c_i)\in P_\cdot$

@Shore I honestly can't follow your most recent comment.

Sorry for my last comments as I didn't make it clear enough. I mean if I only using formula in first order language, can I fully describe vector space. The cause of the question is that for example for predicate, we need to make sure that all $(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in P_\times$ that $a_i$ is in field $F$

continuing last comment, with my understanding in approach 2, we need to put all vectors $V$ and all elements of field $F$ into the structure, which means like $\left<V\cup F, I\right>$ as the structure for language $\mathcal{L}$

I mean first order logic sentence can not describe that for any $(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in P_\times$ that $a_1,a_2,a_3\in F$. It can only describe that for any $(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in P_\times$ there exists $d_i, e_i$ that satisfy $(a_i,d_i,e_i)\in P_\times$

hi thanks, but I think the function symbol $F$ can also be anything. What I mean is that for different structure, the explanation to symbol $P_\times$ can be anything.... How to make sure that using first order language, we can rule out that any $(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in P_\times$ satisfy ${a_1,a_2,a_3}\subset F$

@Shore OK, I honestly have no idea what you're asking. Can you say in words what you think FOL can't express here?

sorry, my bad. let me explain like this, assume that I have field $F$ and vectors on that field $V$, the structure for the language is $\left<F\cup V, I\right>$ that $I$ translate for any $(a,b,c)\in P_\times$ we have $a,b,c\in F$ and $ab=c$. We also may have a structure $\left<F\cup V, I'\right>$ that translate $(a,b,c)\in P_\times$ that translate $a,b,c\in V$ and $ab=c$ in vector multiplication. Now I need a set of formula $T$ so $\left<F\cup V, I'\right>$ cannot satisfy $T$ while $\left<F\cup V, I\right>$ can to tell me that $\left<F\cup V, I\right>$ is field

@Shore Note that in this approach we also have unary predicate symbols picking out the field part and the vectors part (in my answer, I called these symbols $S$ and $V$ respectively). So there is no issue expressing any of this.

ah I understood, thus I think we may simply use function symbol??? because we can write like this $(\forall x_1(\forall x_2(\forall(x_3)(F(x_1)\land F(x_2)\land(\lnot F(x_3)))\to(f_\cdot(f_\times(x_1,x_2),x_3)\hat{=}f_\cdot(x_1,f_\cdot(x_2,x_3))))))$ ??
